# R - Match two columns in two dataframes

Tags: r

I'm trying to manipulate a dataframe where certain conditions are met.

There's the main dataframe df1:

```
Title             Artist        Warner    Sony    Universal
Break My Heart    Dua Lipa      0         0       0
Daisies           Katy Perry    0         0       1
Nicotine          Chef`Special  1         1       0
... 1 000 000+ rows
```

df2:

```
Label       Title            Artist        Operation
Warner      Nicotine         Chef`Special  0
Sony        Break my Heart   Dua Lipa      1
... 100+ rows
```

Df1 contains some mistakes. In this case Nicotine has Warner value 1 while it should be 0. I'm looking to match Title and Artist from both dataframes and then changing the label value to either 1 or 0 depending on df2.

In this instance it should see that Nicotine by Chef'Special is in df1 and df2, and it should change df1$Warner to 0. Break My Heart by Dua Lipa should have df1$Sony set to 1 using the same method.

I have been thinking about how to tackle this for quite some time but I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: How do you determine which df has the correct column value?

Comment: Hi Matt, df2 serves to correct mistakes in df1. So tracks in df1 might have df1$Warner set to 1 while it should be 0. Df2 will contain an entry for that and df2$Operation contains the value it should be. So df2 has the correct column value. 

Would it make it easier if df2 was structured as follows:

```
Title          Artist               Warner    Sony    Universal
Nicotine   Chef'Special    0             1           0
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using merge, didn't have your data so used `mtcars` as an example:

```
df1 = head(mtcars, 5)
df2 = subset(head(within(df1,mpg <-  mpg * 2),2), select = "mpg")


df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 0, all.x = TRUE)
df3 <- within(df3, mpg <- ifelse(is.na(mpg.y), 
                              mpg.x, mpg.y))[-(2:3)]
```